# Pivot Data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, pivot, pivot-table

```
var arr = [
//["Identif", "TAG", "Factor", "Period"],
["0092000115", 1, "0.354", "2019-06"]
["0092000115", 1, "0.354", "2019-05"]
["0092000115", 1, "0.456", "2019-04"]
["0092000115", 1, "0.892", "2019-03"]
["0092000115", 1, "0.654", "2019-02"]
["0092000115", 1, "0.64", "2019-01"]
["0092000115", 2, "0.795", "2019-02"]
["0092000138", 3, "0.654", "2019-03"]
["0092000138", 3, "0.64", "2019-02"]
["0092000138", 3, "0.94", "2019-01"]
["0092000138", 4, "0.795", "2019-04"]
];
```

I want to pivot this data in the format:

```
Identif |TAG | Period0 | Period1 | Period2 | Period3 | Period4 | Period5
```

Like this:

```
[["Identif","TAG", "2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03", "2019-04", "2019-05", "2019-06"],
["0092000115","1", "0.64", "0.654", "0.892", "0.456", "0.354", "0.354"],
["0092000115","2", "-", "0.795", "-", "-", "-", "-"],
["0092000138","3", "0.94", "0.64", "0.654", "-", "-", "-"],
["0092000138","4", "-", "-", "-", "0.795", "-", "-"]]
```

At this moment I have this function (https://techbrij.com/convert-column-to-row-javascript-array-pivot). That allows me to pivot the data only through one column, but in the final result data the column `Identif` is missing.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param dataArray Data to pivot
 * @param col column in array which is to be kept
 * @param colIndex column whose values to be converted as columns
 * @param dataIndex column whose values to be used as data
 */
function getDataPivoted(dataArray, col, colIndex, dataIndex) {
        //Code from https://techbrij.com
        var result = {}, ret = [];
        var newCols = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {

            if (!result[dataArray[i][col]]) {
                result[dataArray[i][col]] = {};
            }
            result[dataArray[i][col]][dataArray[i][colIndex]] = dataArray[i][dataIndex];

            //To get column names
            if (newCols.indexOf(dataArray[i][colIndex]) == -1) {
                newCols.push(dataArray[i][colIndex]);
            }
        }

        newCols.sort();
        var item = [];

        //Add Header Row
        item.push('TAG');
        item.push.apply(item, newCols);
        ret.push(item);

        //Add content 
        for (var key in result) {
            item = [];
            item.push(key);
            for (var i = 0; i < newCols.length; i++) {
                item.push(result[key][newCols[i]] || "-");
            }
            ret.push(item);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

But this leave out information (Identif). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058615/how-to-pivot-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is the same case of the link attached. :(

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to pivot on a composite key of Identif and TAG. Try pre-processing your initial array to concatenate those two columns into one, then pivot.

Comment: @PeterBrand Exactly, but I need Identif, Tag separated to be displayed each in a column in a datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that tags are unique, the column orders are always the same, and the example you gave handles all the cases you would expect. The javascript code below should handle it.

```
function pivot(input_arr) {
    var seen_periods = {};
    var periods_in_order = [];

    var tag_to_identifier = {};
    var tag_to_period_factor = {};

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const row = arr[i];

        if(!tag_to_identifier[row[1]]) {
            tag_to_identifier[row[1]] = row[0];
        }


        if(!tag_to_period_factor[row[1]]) {
            tag_to_period_factor[row[1]] = {}
        }

        tag_to_period_factor[row[1]][row[3]] = row[2];

        if (!seen_periods[row[3]]) {
            seen_periods[row[3]] = true;
        }
    }

    var periods_in_order = Object.keys(seen_periods);
    periods_in_order.sort();

    var all_tags = Object.keys(tag_to_identifier);
    all_tags.sort();

    var header = ["Identif","TAG"];

    periods_in_order.map(function(period) {
        header.push(period);
    })

    var rows = [
        header,
    ];

    all_tags.map(function(tag) {
        var new_row = [ tag_to_identifier[tag], tag ];
        periods_in_order.map(function(period) {
            new_row.push(tag_to_period_factor[tag][period] || "-");
        })

        rows.push(new_row);
    })


    return rows;

}

var arr = [
    ["0092000115", 1, "0.354", "2019-06"],
    ["0092000115", 1, "0.354", "2019-05"],
    ["0092000115", 1, "0.456", "2019-04"],
    ["0092000115", 1, "0.892", "2019-03"],
    ["0092000115", 1, "0.654", "2019-02"],
    ["0092000115", 1, "0.64", "2019-01"],
    ["0092000115", 2, "0.795", "2019-02"],
    ["0092000138", 3, "0.654", "2019-03"],
    ["0092000138", 3, "0.64", "2019-02"],
    ["0092000138", 3, "0.94", "2019-01"],
    ["0092000138", 4, "0.795", "2019-04"]
];

var expected =  [["Identif","TAG", "2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03", "2019-04", "2019-05", "2019-06"],
    ["0092000115","1", "0.64", "0.654", "0.892", "0.456", "0.354", "0.354"],
    ["0092000115","2", "-", "0.795", "-", "-", "-", "-"],
    ["0092000138","3", "0.94", "0.64", "0.654", "-", "-", "-"],
    ["0092000138","4", "-", "-", "-", "0.795", "-", "-"]]

var got = pivot(arr);

console.log("Matches expected: " + (JSON.stringify(expected) === JSON.stringify(got)).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pivod(array) {

    let header = [];
    let identify = {};
    let periods = {}

    array.map((value, index) => {
        if (!identify[value[1]]) identify[value[1]] = value[0];
        if (!periods[value[1]]) periods[value[1]] = {};
        if (periods[value[1]]) periods[value[1]][value[3]] = value[2]

        value.map((innerArr, inerIdx) => {
            if (inerIdx === 3 && !header.includes(innerArr)) header.push(innerArr);
        })

    })
    const identifyKey = Object.keys(identify).sort();
    header.sort()
    
    let result = [header];
    console.log(identifyKey, periods, identify)
    identifyKey.map((indendifyVal, ind) => {
        let bodyRow = [identify[indendifyVal], indendifyVal];
        header.map((headerVal, index) => {
            bodyRow.push(periods[indendifyVal][headerVal] || '_')
        })
        result.push(bodyRow)
    })
    header.unshift(...['Identify', 'TAG']);
    return result;
}
console.log(pivod(arr));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Suggest fixing typos (pivod => pivot) and to use `array.forEach` and not `array.map` when not using the iteration to transform the values.