# how to pivot array javascript/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, pivot, unpivot

hello everyone hoping you are well, I have a question about how to convert an array in js

I have the following array:

```
[
{
id:1
L: 10,
XL: 20
},
{
id:2
L: 40,
XL: 50
}
]
```

and I need it to be like this:

```
[
{
id:1
name: L,
value: 10
},
{
id:1
name: XL,
value: 20
},
{
id:2
name: L,
value: 40
},
{
id:2
name: XL,
value: 50
}
]
```

Thanks for the help.

I am using react, so, any solution with js or react it will great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058615/how-to-pivot-a-javascript-array)

Comment: hi, sorry for that, it updated the question.

Comment: I don't mean to nitpick, but ```id:1``` needs a comma after it. Should help anyone doing a copy/paste to help solve.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3640ym8b/ - That'll be $30

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this by using [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) along with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const inputArr = [{
  id: 1,
  L: 10,
  XL: 20
}, {
  id: 2,
  L: 40,
  XL: 50
}];

const resultArr = [];

inputArr.forEach(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(o => {
    if (o !== 'id') resultArr.push({ id: obj.id, name: o, value: obj[o] })
  })
});

console.log(resultArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I did a foreach over the outer array. In there, I pulled the ID for the current object. Then, I took each entry in the object that wasn't "id", and split it into "name" and "value" as needed.

```
var first = [
    {id:1, L: 10, XL: 20},
    {id:2,L: 40,XL: 50}
];
let result = [];

first.forEach(id => {
    const currentId = id.id
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(id)) {
        if(key !== "id") {
            result.push({id: currentId, name: key, value: value})
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with following way

```
let a= [
        {
        id:1
        L: 10,
        XL: 20
        },
        {
        id:2
        L: 40,
        XL: 50
        }
    ]

    let res=[];
    a.forEach(t=>{
        res.push({
            id:t.id,
            name:'L',
            value:t.L
        })

        res.push({
            id:t.id,
            name:'XL',
            value:t.XL
        })

    })

    console.log("res",res)
```