# How to create table dynamically from an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have a use case to create a table with dynamic data including the header name. I have tried in many ways to reconstruct the array from the API response, But still unable to develop it.

Receiving Array from Response as below

```
[
   {
      "category": "Emergency services",
      "code": "RMY 90",
      "limit": "9032",
      "OT": "4124"
   },
   {
      "category": "Pediatrician",
      "code": "RMY 80",
      "limit": "1232",
      "OT": "9412"
   },
   {
      "category": "Neurology",
      "code": "RMY 70",
      "limit": "6423",
      "OT": "7312"
   }
]
```

Grid Expected array

```
[
   {
      "item": "Block Code",
      "Emergency services": "RMY 90",
      "Pediatrician": "RMY 80",
      "Neurology": "RMY 70"
   },
   {
      "item": "Total Capacity",
      "Emergency services": "9032",
      "Pediatrician": "1232",
      "Neurology": "6423"
   },
   {
      "item": "OT Capacity",
      "Emergency services": "4124",
      "Pediatrician": "9412",
      "Neurology": "7312"
   }
]
```

Table sample
[image]

I have tried with Object.keys() and map but couldn't properly construct the array. since the code is in the client system I couldn't share it. Please help me on reconstruct the array.

My code is

```
const rowList = ["Block Code", "Total Capacity", "OT Capacity"];
  let arr = [];
  const dumming = rowList?.forEach(item => {

    for (const [key, object] of Object.entries(responseData)) {
      let x = [];
      Object.keys(object)?.forEach(item => {
        x.push(object[item]);
      });
      // console.log('rrrr', x);
    }

    let val = responseData.map((ned, index) => {
      let x = {};
      Object.keys(object)?.forEach(item => {
        x = ned[item]
      });
      // let cor = Object.entries(ned).map(([key, leaf]) => key+leaf);
      return {
        id: `${ index }-${ item }`,
        name: item, ...x
      };
    });
    arr.push(val);
  });

  console.log(arr);
```

Im not sure this is correct. Got stuck in something

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pivot array javascript/react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73575757/how-to-pivot-array-javascript-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea to use `rowList` is fine, but it assumes some key order in the input objects (when you later would need to associate the data with each label), and it is generally a bad idea to rely on some *order* in plain objects.

However, your `rowList` serves no purpose: although you iterate it, your code never uses `item` (it defines other `item` variables).

Secondly, you have an unknown variable `object` in the `.map` callback.

I didn't understand why you generate an object with `id` and `name` keys, and produce strings formatted as `${ index }-${ item }` as this does not match anything in your question.

Here is how I would propose to do it:

```js
const responseData = [{"category": "Emergency services","code": "RMY 90","limit": "9032","OT": "4124"},{"category": "Pediatrician","code": "RMY 80","limit": "1232","OT": "9412"},{"category": "Neurology","code": "RMY 70","limit": "6423","OT": "7312"}];

const rowList = [["code", "Block Code"], ["limit", "Total Capacity"], ["OT", "OT Capacity"]];
const result = rowList.map(([key, item]) => ({
    item,
    ...Object.fromEntries(responseData.map((obj) => [obj.category, obj[key]]))
}));

console.log(result);
```